# objective c gcd - should a cancelled operation call a compeletion handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, coding-style, grand-central-dispatch

Many long running async methods have completion handler blocks attached as input parameters to them

I'm not sure if the completion handler should be called if the operation was cancelled.

```
-(void)longRunningAsyncOperation:(Input *)input completionHandler:(Block)completionHandler
{
  // long running code

  // periodic checks for cancelation

  if(_canceled)
  {
   // should completion handler still be called?
   return;
  }

  // more long running code

  // completed
  completionHandler(someData);
}
```

Comment: How about a completion handler that contains information about whether or not the job actually completed. See the UIView animation block. There is a variable `BOOL finished` this signifies whether the animation actually finished or if it was cut short.

Comment: I would recommend `NSOperation` for handling background tasks and cancellation ([NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperation/cancel))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's necessarily one "right answer" here. You should just make it do whatever you need to do. One option, as @Fogmeister proposed in a comment is to make the completion routine take an argument indicating whether it was canceled or completed normally. It would seem advisable to have *something* called in all cases so that an interested party can know that the operation was canceled.

I've seen other APIs that take two different completion blocks -- a "success" block and a "failure" block. To my mind, a single block that takes arguments to indicate status seems like a more adaptable pattern.

If you don't call *any* completion block on cancelation then there is effectively "lost information"; absent some other mechanism, it's impossible for the outside world to know that the operation was canceled, so it seems like one of these patterns, be it an argument to the completion, or success/failure blocks, would be preferable to simply not calling anything.

Answer (score 0):

@ipmcc is correct.  There is generally no one right answer, but best practices generally dictates that you should always call the completion block and, if the completion block actually cares, pass it a success/cancelled flag.  The reason this is a best practice is that some memory may have been allocated as a prelude to the cancelled operation and if you don't call the completion handler, you'll never have the opportunity to free it again.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, it shall call the completion handler.

The rationale for this is, that one can view a completion handler as some form of *return value*.

So, not calling the completion handler is like not returning a value in a function which is declared to return something.